# Include tags in generic "Edited Tags" reason

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

**I propose that names of tags added/removed are included in the generic "Edited Tags" Edit Summary.**

I think this would promote good reviewing and clarify revision history.

---

**Example:** Instead of

> Edited Tags

we would have

> Edited tags: -[html] -[css] +[jquery] +[unicorns]

Comment: @random Disagree. The OP there was happy with tag highlighting.